# Can I use Google Cloud data labeling service to do text classification?

Tags: data-annotations

I have a large dataset with lots of news articles, stored in Google Cloud Storage. I want to train a sentiment classifier (positive, negative, neutral). Does Google has a data labeling service that I can use to create the training data? If yes, where can I find the API documentation?

It looks like Google Cloud AutoML Vision supports human labeling for image classification here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/human-labeling. However, I didn't find the one for text.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud has an alpha version of Data Labeling API, which supports human annotation on text classification, sentiment analysis and other use cases (image, video etc.). You will need to email cloudml-data-customer@google.com to get whitelisted so that you can access their API and documentation.